# While parsing xml/json, skip page if error message received

Tags: php, xml, json

I have following issue. I am parsing an xml feed with multiple pages and there is no way to understand how many they are (I have a variavle set in the xml url, so for each variable there are random number of pages). All I know is that the number can not exceed 50. Now I have a script that autoincrement the variable for the page number starting at 1 and up to 50.

Let's say, that the link has total of 26 pages. With my script I will continue to send requests until the scripts gets to page 50. Than it changes the first variable and starts again from 1 to 50. For the first link, from page 27 forward the xml will return followwing:

```
<response>
    <status>error</status>
    <code>400</code>
    <message>Incorrect Request Headers</message>
</response>
```

How can I make so when the scipt receive this message, to stop the autoincrement and continue by changing the first variable and start again at 1? The code now is:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($row['row_name'] == '') {
        $variable1 = 0;
    }
    else {
        $variable1 = $row['row_name'];
    }

$page = 0;
    do {
        $page++;
        $result = apiCall('option1', 'option2', array('option3' => $variable1, 'page' => $page));
        usleep(1000);
        $res = json_decode($result);
            foreach ($res->node1->node2 as $item) {

            //define variable for insertion in MySQL

            $sql1 to insert the variables
            if (!mysql_query($sql1,$con1))
            {
                die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
            }
        }
    }
    while ($page<=50);
}
```

In the above code, only the `$variable1` and `$page` are variables. All options (1, 2 and 3) are predefined and stay the same. I.e. I need when the script gets the error message to start again from 1 with next value of `$variable1`.

Comment: What does the apiCall do?  Looks like it's getting the webpage?  More specifically, what's in $result?  The full XML?  Something else?

Comment: It is the full feed in json format. If the page is false i.e. no data in it the output will be as stated in the beggining: status:"error". If there is data status is equal ti success. I have played with php break but no result.

Comment: Break is a good way of handling this . . . let's see the code you had with the break?  You should be able to check $result before you do the json_decode, and if it's empty, break . . .

Comment: Just to be clear - there is no empty page. If there is no data that I need (i.e. the content within <message> you will see the error message as stated above. Not 500 error for example.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Here is the code I played around:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($row['row_name'] == '') {
        $variable1 = 0;
    }
    else {
        $variable1 = $row['row_name'];
    }

$page = 1;
    do {
        $result = apiCall('option1', 'option2', array('option3' => $variable1, 'page' => $page));
        usleep(1000);
        $res = json_decode($result);
    if ($res->status == 'error') {
            break 2;
        }
            foreach ($res->node1->node2 as $item) {

            //define variable for insertion in MySQL

            $sql1 to insert the variables
            if (!mysql_query($sql1,$con1))
            {
                die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
            }
        }
        $page++;
    }
    while (0);
}
```

The problem is that it stops the script execution at some point. Can not understand why.

Comment: Ops. There was my mistake in the error code. So the above code works with the proper statement within the if () i.e. break 2; does the job.